Run VSCode task inside WSL and windows sequentially
Configured WSL to successfully compile my framework there.
I've installed VSCode in Windows with WSL integration extension.
With shell task type I successfully can trigger building framework from VSCode.
My workflow assumes now that I run in Windows (2) packaging tool and then (3) install package on tablet.
Is it possible to setup VSCode tasks to RUN inside WSL and other task to run in Windows (with CMD or PowerShell)?
PS: I found one solution in reverting my approach.
In bottom-left VSCode corner there's button WSL: distro where I can order to Reopen Folder in Windows.
Now, by default, all shell type tasks start in PowerShell. I can call WSL directly with
"command" : "C:\\Windows\\System32\\wsl.exe"**
"args": [
        "-e",
        "bash",
        "-lic",
        "source /home/tangl/.bash_build && build_fw_make"
        ]

I can set tasks in sequence with packaging and installing called in Windows.
